# Cut off table content for the next cell CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm building a list by using a table:

[image: table screenshot]

As you can see, the long url, makes the table wider. This is what I want to prevent.

I've used a couple of things like

```
table { table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; }
```

and

```
td.title { white-space:nowrap;overflow: hidden; width: 200px; }
```

But this did not work.

Also, maybe I need to note that my table is dynamically being made. But this should not be a problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide a fiddle for this, so we can edit the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cut the url text (not the href value) at a certain character. With JavaScript you can do that with `str.substring(5, 0);` where 5 is the number of characters you want left.

Answer (score 0):

This is default behaviour of a table cell. It will always stretch to fit the content's dimensions. `width` on a table cell tends to behave more like `min-width`

The fix is to not style the `td`, but instead its contents only.

Try something like:

```
td.title a {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}
```